# Como tratar colunas com mesmo nome em arquivo csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tenho o seguinte problema, recebi uma base de dados em arquivo csv e preciso fazer uma análize desses dados, porém tem um monte de colunas com o mesmo nome e eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de tratar essas colunas **sem alterar o arquivo** em si, apenas manipulando o dataframe.

Código para gerar o dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
base = pd.read_csv('Final_behavior_study_results.csv')
```

Como as colunas aparecem:

```
# | Describe your experience | what is the feeling in this photo? | what is the feeling in this photo? | what is the feeling in this photo? | Start Date | Submite Date | Network ID
```

Comment: Você pode renomear todas as colunas passando uma lista com os novos nomes, por exemplo: `df.columns = ["col1", "col2"]`

Comment: Thiago, bom dia! Se elas tem o mesmo nome talvez seja interessante pivotar seu DF. Caso queira disponibilizar o arquivo csv podemos ter uma noção maior do que se trata. Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito estranho. O pandas já trata isso.

Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935835/read-duplicate-column-names-in-csv-file)

crie um arquivo `teste.csv` contendo

```
a,b,a
1,2,3
```

Depois use no Python

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(open("teste.csv", "r"))
>>> df
   a  b  a.1
0  1  2    3
```

Veja que a segunda coluna `a` recebeu um `.1` ficando `a.1` e no csv somente havia `a`

Verifique se há espaços extras no nome do campo.

Espero que ajude